# PythonでAizu Onlineジャッジの最大公約数と最小公倍数の問題でRuntime Errorと出る。

Tags: python, python3

Aizu Onlineジャッジの[最大公約数と最小公倍数の問題](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=0005&lang=jp)をPython3で解いていますが、「Runtime Error」（はやく言えばスクリプト言語単位でのエラーですね）と出てしまいます。
どこに「Runtime Error」の原因があるのか教えてくれないでしょうか。

```
class GCD():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def swap(self):
        temp = self.a
        self.a = self.b
        self.b = temp

    def gcd(self):
        if self.b < self.a:
            self.swap()

        temp = self.b % self.a

        if temp == 0:
            ans = self.a
            return ans

        ans = self.b % temp

        return ans


    def lcm(self):
        gcd = self.gcd()
        temp = self.a * self.b
        ans = temp // gcd
        return gcd,ans

    def print(self):
        num = self.lcm()
        print("{0} {1}".format(num[0],num[1]))

def main():
    data = []

    while 1:
        try:
            n = input().split()

            a = int(n[0])
            b = int(n[1])

            data.append(GCD(a, b))

        except EOFError:
            break

    for array in data:
        array.print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 参考:最大公約数と最小公倍数を求める公式には[ユーグリッドの互除法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%92%E9%99%A4%E6%B3%95)を使っています。

Comment: gcd function 内で `temp = self.b % self.a`,  `ans = self.b % temp` となっていますが、`self.b` が `self.a` の倍数の場合、`temp` が `0` になりますので、`ans = self.b % temp` で `ZeroDivisionError` が発生する事になります。

Comment: @metropolis さんのご指摘どおりに、`self.b`が`self.a`の倍数なら、`self.a`を返すようにしたのですが、Runtime Errorのままです。

Comment: ご参考まで: https://goo.gl/tU2iGY

Comment: コードの変更を投稿にも反映していただけますか？

Comment: @letrecさん、反映いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

色々と回答を出しているみたいですが、Kenji Noguchiさんの意見を参考にして、コードを以下のように変更したら「Accept」（正解です）になりました。みなさま、どうもありがとうございました！！

```
class GCD():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def gcd(self):
        if self.a < self.b:
            self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a
        while self.b:
            self.a, self.b= self.b, self.a % self.b

        return self.a

    def print(self):
        lcm = self.a * self.b // self.gcd()
        print(self.gcd(), lcm)

def main():
    data =[]

    while 1:
        try:
            n = input().split()

            a = int(n[0])
            b = int(n[1])

            data.append(GCD(a, b))

        except EOFError:
            break

    for array in data:
        array.print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```